# Issue with gdalUtils vs. raster in gridding data in R

Tags: raster, r, rasterization, gdalutils, gdal-grid

I have irregularly spaced data (XYZ) and I'm trying to grid it in R using 2 different libraries, `gdalUtils` and `raster`.  I'd prefer to use `gdalUtils` as I have more options, but the output looks off.  To use `gdalUtils` I create a CSV file with columns named x, y, and z.  I then create a VRT file so that the GDAL function `gdal_grid` can be used.  My code,

```
## load libraries
library(ncdf4); library(raster); library(gdalUtils)

## download file and open      
file = 'http://ncss.hycom.org/thredds/ncss/grid/GLBa0.08/expt_90.9/2012?var=mld&north=47&west=277&east=320&south=22&disableProjSubset=on&horizStride=1&time=2012-01-01T00%3A00%3A00Z&vertCoord=&addLatLon=true&accept=netcdf'
saveFile = tempfile(, fileext = 'nc')
download.file(file, saveFile, mode = 'wb')
ncOpen = nc_open(saveFile)

## get data
x = ncvar_get(nc = ncOpen, varid = 'Longitude') - 360
y = ncvar_get(nc = ncOpen, varid = 'Latitude')
z = ncvar_get(nc = ncOpen, varid = 'mld')

## replace NA with a fillValue
z[is.na(z)] = -9999

## create a data.frame
df = data.frame(x = c(x), y = rev(c(y)), z = c(z))

## close .nc file
nc_close(ncOpen)

## create a temp directory
temporary_dir = getwd()

## base dir path
tempfname_base = file.path(temporary_dir, 'hycom')

## create a properly formatted CSV
tempfname_csv = paste0(tempfname_base, '.csv')
write.csv(df, file = tempfname_csv, row.names = FALSE)

## tiff file for saving
tempfname_tif = paste0(tempfname_base, '.tiff')

## create VRT file
tempfname_vrt = paste0(tempfname_base, '.vrt')
vrt_header = c(
    '<OGRVRTDataSource>',
    '\t<OGRVRTLayer name="hycom">',
    '\t<SrcDataSource>hycom.csv</SrcDataSource>',
    '\t<GeometryType>wkbPoint</GeometryType>',
    '\t<GeometryField encoding="PointFromColumns" x="x" y="y" z="z"/>',
    '\t</OGRVRTLayer>',
    '\t</OGRVRTDataSource>'
)
vrt_filecon = file(tempfname_vrt, 'w')
writeLines(vrt_header, con = vrt_filecon)
close(vrt_filecon)

## now run gdal_grid
ras = gdal_grid(src_datasource = tempfname_vrt, dst_filename = tempfname_tif, a = paste0('nearest:nodata=', -9999, ':radius1=0.08333333:radius2=0.08333333'), txe = c(-83, -40), tye = c(22, 47), outsize = c(538, 385), a_srs = '+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0', of = 'GTiff', ot = 'Float64', l = 'hycom', output_Raster = TRUE, verbose = FALSE)
```

Everything runs fine, but when you plot the output raster and overlay the U.S. coastline you can see there is an issue.

[image]

However, if I use `rasterize` from the `raster` library everything looks good.  Here's my code,

```
x = ncvar_get(nc = ncOpen, varid = 'Longitude') - 360
y = ncvar_get(nc = ncOpen, varid = 'Latitude')
z = ncvar_get(nc = ncOpen, varid = 'mld')
df = data.frame(x = c(x), y = c(y), z = c(z))
eRas = raster(ncol = 538, nrow = 385)
extent(eRas) = c(-83, -40, 22, 47)
proj4string(eRas) = '+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0'
ras = rasterize(df[,c('x', 'y')], eRas, df$z)
```

[image]

I can't figure out why `gdal_grid` is giving me an image that looks offset.  The input data is exactly the same in both cases.